# VSTO project will not load after upgrading office

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-2013

We have recently installed Office 2013 on our development PCs. After installing Office 2013, we are no longer able to load our VSTO project (Word Add-in) in Visual Studio. Any ideas why this would be and what we can do to load the project?

In the solution explorer it says `Load failed` and the details are that `a project with this name has already been loaded in the solution`.

**Note**: *Another developer with Office 2010 is still able to load the project just fine so the variable here is definitely Office 2013*.

**UPDATE**: I found the following on MSDN wrt to the same error experienced from 2003 - 2010:

> To resolve this issue, edit the .vbproj or .csproj file. For a Word
>   project, replace HostPackage="{763FDC83-64E5-4651-AC9B-28C4FEB985A1}"
>   with HostPackage="{6CE98B71-D55A-4305-87A8-0D6E368D9600}". For an
>   Excel project, replace
>   HostPackage="{B284B16A-C42C-4438-BDCD-B72F4AC43CFB}" with
>   HostPackage="{825100CF-0BA7-47EA-A084-DCF3308DAF74}". For an Outlook
>   project, replace HostPackage="{D2B20FF5-A6E5-47E1-90E8-463C6860CB05}"
>   with HostPackage="{20A848B8-E01F-4801-962E-25DB0FF57389}".
>
> Alternatively, ensure that migrated projects are only opened on
>   development computers with Microsoft Office 2010 already installed.

So it looks as though I just need to find the right GUID to replace the HostPackage ID with. Any idea where I'd find the correct ID?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? I have Office 2007 and 2013 Preview installed side-by-side using VS2010 targeting Office 2007 without issue.

Comment: Do you have both Office 2010 and 2013 installed on your machine?

Comment: Office 2013 only. We don't have a side by side installation of office on  our PCs

Comment: Do you know whether Office 2013 was installed by means of Click-To-Run?

Comment: Have a look at this post - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officedevpreview/thread/7a407f98-fb88-43c8-b22f-a07542e24678 haven't tried it myself but it may be helpful